# Move Sharepoint list with views from SBS to Sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, small-business-server

I wonder what is the best way to move a sharepoint list with different views from sbs to sharepoint online?

is there any other easier way than creating the list manually in shatepoint online and creating the view,  then exporting all objects from the sbs (companyweb) list to excel and importing them  in sharepoint online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to move the list to SharePoint online separately, I recommend that you take the method of saving the list as a template.

1.Save your list as a template.

2.Copy the template file to your desktop.

3.Go to your top-level site collection settings in SP Online and go to "List Templates" from the Designer Galleries section.

4.Upload your list template.

5.Create a new list using that template.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use the free Microsoft SharePoint Migration Tool. It will create whole site collections, including content, views and more.